# Not using a sqlite database, but django project throws sqlite error

Tags: django

When I cancel out of runserver, this error displays before it fully cancels:

> "ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread"

The thing is, I'm using a mysql database, not sqlite!

Does anyone know what's really going on here?

Comment: Can you give more details about what is throwing this error? Like what module, is it third party or django built in?

Comment: show your settings file can help more info